# Different sized rows in tables populated by php

Tags: php, html

So I made this div that is populated by php calls to my server to populate it with a table per entry in the Server table. Aka, a php script connects to my server, checks how many entries there are, and creates a table for each one to populate the div. So in the end there are several table entries displayed corresponding to each entry in the database.

I don't know of a jsfiddle/codepin type place that allows php since it's server-side so I took a picture to show what it looks like. The arrows are pointing to the two entries where the box they are in is wider than the others. This happens any time I do not include a link (an optional entry in the database). I assume this is because it is trying to fill the space left by having no link in the last table row, but the last part of my php script should have removed that last row if it was empty (assuming I wrote it correctly) and it shouldn't need to stretch to fill something no longer there.

So, what I'm asking here is how do I make each of the orange rows the same size?

Picture of the box: http://i67.tinypic.com/5k3nzs.png

HTML (Relevant portion)

```
<div id="announcements_box">
  <h2>Announcements</h2>
  <?php include "scripts/php/getAnnouncement.php";?>
  <div class="bottom_color"></div>
 </div> <!--end announcement_box-->
```

CSS (Relevant portion)

```
#announcements_box{
   table-layout: fixed;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   width: 47%;
   color: black;
   margin-left: 1rem;
   border-top-left-radius: 30px;
   border-top-right-radius: 30px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;     
}

#announcements_box h2{
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 2rem;
   background-color: navy;
   color: white;
   border-top-left-radius: 25px;
   border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.announcement_blocks{
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: .5rem; /* space after each block */
   background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

.announcement_blocks img{
  /* height: 75px; */
   width: 75px;
   margin: .5rem;
   padding-top: 1rem;
}

.announcement_blocks td{  
   /* word-wrap: break-word;
   word-break: break-all; 
   */
}

.announcement_blocks td.title{
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #E18A07;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.announcement_blocks td.descr{
   padding-left: 1rem;
   padding-right: 1rem; 
}

.announcement_blocks td.link{
   text-align: center;
   /*
   padding-left: 1rem;
   padding-right: 1rem;  
   */
}

.announcement_blocks td.img_s{  
   width: 1rem;
   background-color: #330000;
}

.bottom_color{
   height: 2.5rem;
   background-color: navy;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
   margin-top: -.5rem;
}
```

PHP (Relevant portion)

```
<?php require "scripts/php/database_connect.php"?>

<?php
   $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Announcements") or die("Error in query. Details: ".mysqli_error());
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
?>



   <table class="announcement_blocks">
      <tr>
         <td class="img_s" rowspan="3"><?php echo "<img src='/img/announcement_icon/announcement_imp.png" . "' alt='announcement'>";?></td>
         <td class="title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>       
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="descr"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
      </tr>

         <?php if($row['link'] != "")
         {
           ?>
            <td class="link"><a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>"><?php echo $row['link']; ?></a></td>
         <?php
         }
            ?>   
   </table>

<?php
   }
?>
```

I know this is long and probably a bit confusing since I can't just hand you a fiddle or codepin to toy with but any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: send the live url?

Comment: it's running on my xampp server and it's only configured for local network access at the moment. For this I'd rather not throw it on some random server as it does have some sensitive information

Comment: i posted the answer check it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bottom if links are there its working, if not there its height increased.

to avoid this you can give

```
 <?php if($row['link'] != ""){?>
            <a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>"><?php echo $row['link']; ?></a>
 <?}else { echo "<br>";}?>
```

Comment: Indeed...simple as that I guess. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this php code:

```
<?php
   $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Announcements") or die("Error in query. Details: ".mysqli_error());
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>

   <table class="announcement_blocks">
      <tr>
         <td class="img_s" rowspan="3"><?php echo "<img src='/img/announcement_icon/announcement_imp.png" . "' alt='announcement'>";?></td>
         <td class="title"><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>       
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="descr"><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="link">
            <?php if($row['link'] != ""){?>
            <a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>"><?php echo $row['link']; ?></a>
            <?}?>
         </td>
      </tr> 
   </table>

<?}?>
```